# What is the logic proof that ¬ (∃x)(Fx) => (∀x)(Fx → Gx)

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

I need to prove the proposition ¬ (∃x)(Fx) => (∀x)(Fx → Gx) but haven't really found a good way. I started off this way:

1. ¬ (∃x)(Fx) Premise
2. ¬ (∀x)(Fx → Gx) Conclution
3. (∃x)[ ¬ (Fx → Gx)] Negation distribution in 2
4. (∃x)[¬(¬Fx˅Gx)] Material implication in 3

Feel like I'm close to the answer but still no concrete way to prove this. Any comments or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Start with the premise. Move negation inside. $(\forall x)\neg F(x)$. Then $(\forall x)\neg F(x) \lor G(x)$. Then conclusion.

Comment: What proof system are you asked to use ? *Natural Deduction*, logical equivalences, ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i'm asked to use logical equivalences

Comment: Basically, you have to use the equivalence between $\lnot \exists$ and $\forall \lnot$ and then use [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) to get rid of the leading quantifier. Now, from $\lnot Fx$ use [Disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) to derive $\lnot Fx \lor Gx$ and then use [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) to derive : $Fx \to Gx$. Now [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before attempting to construct a formal proof of anything, you should have an informal reason to believe it is true.  I suggest:

- $\lnot \exists \langle x,~ Fx \rangle$ means $F$ is always false
- $\forall \langle x,~ Fx \implies Gx \rangle$ follows from "false always implies anything ($G$ in this case)"

A constructed proof should follow that general outline.  Here is a natural deduction one:

$$\begin{array} {l}
%
\quad \begin{array} {|l} \lnot \exists \langle x,~ Fx \rangle \\ \hline
%
\quad \begin{array} {|l} Fy \\ \hline
%
\exists \langle x,~ Fx \rangle \\
%
\bot \\
%
Gy \end{array} \\
%
\forall \langle x,~ Fx \implies Gx \rangle  \end{array} \\
%
\lnot \exists \langle x,~ Fx \rangle \implies \forall \langle x,~ Fx \implies Gx \rangle \end{array}$$